# Ethernet from router to raspberry pi zero W

Tags: pi-zero-w, internet

Is there a way to plugin a raspberry Pi Zero W in to a WIFI router like BT smart hub 2 and it get internet through the usb port[image: ending setup]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You can turn the Raspberry Pi zero into a USB gadget and configure it to be a network device yes.